# Sidebar layout where only the content div is scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a sidebar layout like the one in the picture:
[image: Layout sketch]

The height of the sidebar is 100%; The Menu 1, Menu 2.. header and the div container below (the one with numbers) should also stay visible.

The only appearing scroll should be in the content div and only if the content is long enough.

What i have so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oadQQE

HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aside{
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header ul li{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.fixed{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.content{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class-"aside">
  <header class="header">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="fixed">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: leaving this for future reference from W3Schools:
Note: The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

Comment: There's a typo in `<div class-"aside">`. This causes the `.aside` selector to not match because your aside element has an invalid `class` attribute. Replace the minus with an equal sign.

Comment: Fixed!! And it works now , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `display: flex` on the sidebar itself with a `flex-direction: column;`.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aside {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header ul li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fixed {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside">
  <header class="header">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="fixed">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error nulla animi atque odit est beatae deleniti totam accusantium. Saepe dicta ex dignissimos voluptate consequuntur beatae animi. Nihil, sequi minima. Minima.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione quibusdam in eveniet eos tempore quia magni quam ipsum illo est, veniam maiores repudiandae culpa ut! Odio a asperiores nam ipsum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, maiores? Magnam assumenda, odit maxime optio, ipsa aut beatae iste expedita perspiciatis eius, earum rerum vel labore laudantium nulla delectus blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```